# Unable to resolve module 'module://graphql/language/parser.js'

Tags: typescript, react-native, npm, graphql, expo

I am trying to make a React Native TypeScript project on Snack Expo. Although I have already added graphql in the package.json as well as the types file, I still get this error :

```
Device: (1:8434) Unable to resolve module 'module://graphql/language/parser.js'
  Evaluating module://graphql/language/parser.js
  Evaluating module://graphql-tag.js
  Evaluating module://graphql/loadCountries.tsx.js
  Evaluating module://App.tsx.js
  Loading module://App.tsx
```

How can I fix this? I am not using an JS Files. Here's the link to the expo:

https://snack.expo.io/qYOFLsmjv

Comment: just ran yarn add graphql, restarted the React Native packager and this particular error went away. Still trying to figure out the rest of it

Comment: Do we have a terminal on Snack Expo to do this? Couldn't figure it out @MelanRashitha

Answer (score 8):

In my case I install `graphql` to made this error go away.
Also I used `graphql-request` package which by default do not install `graphql` as a dependency so I added it this way.

```sh
npm install graphql
```

Comment: This worked for me when I had a graphql issue tied to Amplify and an outdated dep for a qr code maker.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is comes when you use `import gql from 'graphql-tag'`. Honestly I don't know why `graphql-tag` not working in **snack.expo.io**, however it is working on react-native project.

But I have found the solution. I have added `"@apollo/client": "3.3.6"` (use latest version) as dependency in **package.json** and then imported `gql` from `@apollo/client` like this :

```js
import { gql } from '@apollo/client';
```

And it worked.